# RecyclerView at the bottom of Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to achieve something similar to Field Trip app like this image:

[image]

Below is my fragment layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/map_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:reverseLayout="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

But am not able to see the RecyclerView, instead Map is occupying full height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this   use `LinearLayout` and  give `android:layout_weight="1"` to your `<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` and give  `android:layout_weight="1"` to your `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` like below layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

  <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/map_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:reverseLayout="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take `LinearLayout` inside `FrameLayout` and use weightSum;

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2.0" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/map_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:reverseLayout="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LinearLayout` with percentage weights (60% for `maps` and 40% for `RecyclerView`)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum = "1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/map_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight = "0.40"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:reverseLayout="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/map_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:reverseLayout="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with FrameLayout used. Just Change FrameLayout to LinearLayout, will be good. So it it should be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/map_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:reverseLayout="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take linear layout with vertical orientation inside the mainLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/map_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:reverseLayout="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope the code will make you help out